# aws kinesis firehose to aws elasticsearch via lambda, how to modify or delete?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis-firehose, aws-elasticsearch

i'm trying incremental indexing kinesis firehose => lambda transform => amazon es.

The insert example is like that

```
const output = event.records.map((record) => {
    return {
        recordId: record.recordId,
        result: 'Ok',
        data: record.data,
    }
});
```

But how to modify, or delete specific index?

Seems to enable via http request, but the transform requires recordId, result, data as return value, in this [doc.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/data-transformation.html)

Does anyone could answer about that?